# Doctrine 2.1.5 setFirstResult() produce error in MySQL 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

This query :

```
$this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery("SELECT k FROM FooBarBundle:Kode k WHERE k.kode LIKE :keyword OR k.nama LIKE :keyword ORDER BY k.kode ASC")
            ->setParameter("keyword", "%$keyword%")
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->setFirstResult($offset)
        ->getResult();
```

Generate the following SQL error :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OFFSET 0' at line 1
```

But if I remove the `setFirstResult($offset)` line, it works fine. Is there any workaround for this instead of upgrading the whole Doctrine library (a patch might be fine)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must remove

```
ORDER BY k.kode ASC
```

from your query and set it with method like this:

```
$this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery("SELECT k FROM FooBarBundle:Kode k WHERE k.kode LIKE :keyword OR k.nama LIKE :keyword")
            ->setParameter("keyword", "%$keyword%")
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->setFirstResult($offset)
            ->orderBy("k.kode")
            ->getResult();
```